# TensorFlow C++, runtime issue

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have created a model using TensorFlow python. Now I have loaded the model in C++ and run it using session->Run (feeding input tensors). The code is complied and linked well, however as soon as it reaches the session->Run during the run time, It doesn't proceed further, and it doesn't create any error message either! It looks like it runs forever! I also checked the CPU usage, but it does not also indicate any intensive computation!

Comment: Please read the posting guidelines concerning a minimal example. Your question as it stands is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

When a TensorFlow program blocks forever, one common issue is that the step is blocked on an empty queue in a [`q.dequeue()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.dequeue) or [`q.dequeue_many()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.dequeue_many) op.

One possibility is that your Python model depends on prefetching threads (derived from [`tf.train.QueueRunner`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/api_docs/python/train.html#QueueRunner) objects). Many of the input reading  (e.g. using [`tf.TFRecordReader`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#TFRecordReader)), and batching (e.g. using [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch)) pipelines implicitly create queues and queue runners.

If you had to run [`tf.train.start_queue_runners()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/api_docs/python/train.html#start_queue_runners) in your Python program, then you will need to do the equivalent thing in your C++ code, by forking threads to run the appropriate `q.enqueue()` ops. Alternatively, you can prepare the input in your C++ program and feed the graph so that the operations you are trying to run do not depend on dequeuing elements for a queue.